# Download file from FTP server to client using Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

**System architecture**

System consist of 3 components

1: **FTP server**: Used to store files. Can only be accessed by Node.js app. No direct access.

2: **Node.js**: Provides an API to interact with **FTP server**. Only way to interact with **FTP server**. Node.js app have no collection of files stored on FTP. Only provides method to work with FTP. Node.js app should not store any file uploaded from it and download from it.

3: **Client**: A user how will upload or download a file to **FTP server** by using **Node.js app**.

**What I have done**:

I am able to download the file stored on FTP by using `basic-ftp` package. Here is the code for download file function.

```js
async function downloadFile(folderPath, fileName, writeStream) {
    console.log(folderPath);
    console.log(fileName);
    const client = new ftp.Client()
    // client.ftp.verbose = true
    try {
        await client.access({
            'host': process.env.FTP_HOST,
            'user': process.env.FTP_USER,
            'password': process.env.FTP_PASSWORD,
        });
        await client.ensureDir(folderPath);
        await client.downloadTo(writeStream, fileName);
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    client.close()
}
```

The file is download to the directory named `/downloads` on Node.js server. What I want to do actually is download the file directly to client computer. To download the file directly to client, I have tried streaming the `writeStream` object from download method. Here is the code for that

```js
app.post("/download/file", urlencodedParser, (req, res, next) => {
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./downloads/'+req.body.fileName);
    writeStream.on("data", (data) => {
      res.write(data);
    })
    writeStream.on("close", () => {
      res.end()
    })

    res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
    downloadFile(req.body.folderName, req.body.fileName, writeStream);
})
```

This does not work. It always ends in error with downloading the file completely.

Another approach I tried is to generate a URL for the file and client will click the URL to download the file. Problem with this approach is the file is not complete by the time I start downloading which results in incomplete file download. For example, If the size of file is 10MB and only 2 MB was download by the time client clicked the link, it will download only 2MB file not 10MB.

**Goal**:

Download the file to client(browser) from a FTP server through Node js.

**Requirement**:

Download the file stored on FTP server directly to client through Node js.

**Constraints**:

Client does not have access to FTP server.

The only way to access the server is through Node js app.

Comment: Hello, so basically you want to 'bridge' FROM server (USING NodeJS) TO client, So that the Client never sees the MAIN server, just the NodeJS server, is that it?

Comment: Yes. I want to bridge FROM server TO client.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but i think this can be done with the 'net' module from nodejs, you could just 'pipe' the connection from the server, to the client, and the server would only see the nodejs server, and the client would only see the nodejs server as well!

try it...

Comment: you just have to include manually the FTP credentials on connection, before the pipe...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to indicate `res` as an output stream directly. That way you will simply redirect a stream from an ftp to a client:

```
async function downloadFile(fileName, writeStream) {
    console.log(fileName);
    const client = new ftp.Client()
    // client.ftp.verbose = true
    try {
        await client.access({
            'host': process.env.FTP_HOST,
            'user': process.env.FTP_USER,
            'password': process.env.FTP_PASSWORD,
        });
        await client.downloadTo(writeStream, fileName);
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    client.close()
}

app.post("/download/file", urlencodedParser, (req, res, next) => {
    downloadFile(req.body.fileName, res);
})
```